# Sort array by values of other array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm having trouble sorting a hand of cards with Javascript, partly due to the fact I keep trying to figure out when to use an array and when an object, and partly because Javascript just isn't as easy to work with as, say, PHP when it comes to arrays. I also can't use jQuery because this is server-side Node.js code and I want to stick to pure Javascript.

This is how the hand is formatted to begin with:

```
[ 'QD', '8H', 'QS', '10C', '10D', '7D', 'KH', '9S' ]
```

As you see, each card is noted as rank+suit, so QD is Queen of Diamonds, 8H is 8 of Hearts etc. It is not acceptable to sort them alphabetically. The way I need to sort them is by values given in the following array, from highest to lowest:

```
[ QD: 25,
  '8H': 32,
  QS: 45,
  '10C': 17,
  '10D': 27,
  '7D': 21,
  KH: 36,
  '9S': 43 ]
```

As a side note, can someone tell me why some of the card names have `'`s around them and some don't? The above is the output from `console.log`, and all 'card names' were initialized the same way.

So the array should look like:

```
[ 'QS', '9S', 'KH', '8H', '10D', 'QD', '7D', '10C' ]
```

I know what needs to be done logically but I don't know how to accomplish it in Javascript. In PHP, I would sort the array of card values, then use a `foreach` loop to go through it, where `key` would be the card; then create a hand array with the keys of this array. But in Javascript I'm not sure how to even get the keys for the array.

Comment: Some keys have quotes around them because you can't start a variable/key name in JS with an number, iirc.

Comment: Can't you just sort the object and get the keys with `Object.keys(obj)`?

Comment: @Andy Thanks - but does that have any effect on functionality?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to map Queen for 11, Aces for 13 etc. and then map Spades before Hearts etc. and sort based on that instead of another array with hardcoded values for each card.

Comment: The quotes don't affect the functionality. If your OCD kicks in and you're irked that some have them and some don't, quote them all.

Comment: I'll even whip up an example -> http://jsfiddle.net/7pb3v/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var ranks = { 
  'QD': 25,
  '8H': 32,
  'QS': 45,
  '10C': 17,
  '10D': 27,
  '7D': 21,
  'KH': 36,
  '9S': 43 };

var toSort = [ 'QD', '8H', 'QS', '10C', '10D', '7D', 'KH', '9S' ];

toSort.sort(function(left, right) {
   return ranks[right] - ranks[left]; // descending order
});
```

Alternatively, you could just use the ranks map, and get the suits array via:

```
Object.keys(ranks).sort(...same_as_above...)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! But could you explain the code to me a bit, or point me to a resource that does? I really don't understand the syntax at all, what are `left` and `right` here? How does the difference between `ranks[left]` and `ranks[right]` give us a sorted array?

Comment: So, basically I am supplying my own comparison functions. Left and right are just elements to compare from the list. You could also call them elementA and elementB if you like. For more info see this MDN article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fsort